# Android: DOM-Model to XML

Tags: android, xml

analogue to this one ([Replacing XML in File from "Document" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788345/replacing-xml-in-file-from-document-in-java) or 
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.transform/WriteDom.html) I try to use it under Android...

The problem is, that I can't use the suggested solution under android, because it throws java.lang.verifyError...

After reading a little bit, I found out, that the class that was used to store the data to file, is not usable in android...

can you suggest another solution, which is similar easy to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link should also show a good example from IBM how to use DOM to XML on Android

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#N1025A

Answer (score 1):

That code should work directly on Android, but unluckily **from API level 8**, that includes  [Java XML Transformer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/transform/dom/package-summary.html).

Unluckily this version of Android is rather new (days) and no official phone firmware based on this platform version is out yet for any current terminal (but Nexus One), though at least some manufacturers stated that they would be supporting it on recently released models: [HCT](http://www.thinkdigit.com/Mobiles-PDAs/HTC-announces-Android-22-support-for-its_4614.html), [Motorola](http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/24/motorola-expects-android-2-2-update-to-hit-droid-in-the-near-fu/).

Comment: mh...seems nice, but I want to develop on API level 7(or lower if possible)
But it is a nice hint ;-) -> Upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XMLSerializer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html).

Example :

```
FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
BufferedOutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

XmlSerializer serializer = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newSerializer();
serializer.setOutput(buf, "utf-8");
serializer.startDocument("utf-8", Boolean.TRUE);
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
serializer.startTag(null, "yourRootTag");
```

... and so on. Android API docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
This seems to me, that I have to iterate through the whole document and manually put this into the XML file?